# Can I get a control's Binding Path in Xamarin forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin

Is there a way to retrieve the binding path of a control in Xamarin Forms?

```
public partial class TestPage : _BaseContentPage
{
    public TestPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Binding b = new Binding("Field1", BindingMode.OneWay, null, null, null, this.BindingContext);
        Entry t = FindByName("Field1") as Entry;
        t.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, b);

        // Now, how do I get the Binding path back?
        // Binding b2 = t.GetBinding();   // no such animal.
    }
}
```

OR In XAML

```
<!-- Field1 - string -->
<Label Text="Field 1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
<StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0" Padding="0">
    <Entry x:Name="Field1" Text="{Binding Field1}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Keyboard="Default" />
    <Label Text="{Binding [Field1]}" TextColor="Red" FontSize="Small" IsVisible="{Binding [Field1], Converter={StaticResource stringToBool}}" />
</StackLayout>
```

I am trying to emulate the effortless binding that angular offers but Xamarin and XAML don't seem to be equipped to handle things like keeping track of whether or not a control has been 'touched' or changed 'dirty' so I have to use code behind (sacrilege I know!). The only way I can think of is to track these states using control events where I get the control itself but no binding information. I am planning to bite the bullet and just give all my controls names that match the properties they are bound to so I can track their states in the ViewModel but it would be REALLY nice just to be able to get the path I assigned it in the XAML so I don't have to maintain a name in two places.

Comment: Neither BindingContext nor BindableObject have any methods that would help you search for a binding. as a workaround, you would have to create the bindings in code (not XAML), and create your own association (dictionary) between views (or viewmodels?) and binding names. Maybe you can create and cache the BindableProperties involved in the bindings?

Comment: Lucas Zhang - Yeah I was afraid of that. I googled quite a while and found nothing. Oh well, as long as the control names match the property names I can just get the name from the control events in the base Content page and apply the states to a dictionary in the Bound ViewModel.

Comment: Yes , you could use this workaround .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this was asked long ago. I came to a similar situation where I had to get the Entry fields binding path from the code to construct my validation control logic.

GetBindingPath() below gives me the binding path of the control it is currently set to. Example:
[image]

Then this gives me the path of each of the above control's 'ValueTextProperty' binding path i.e "AccountsSignupModel.xxxxxPropertyxxx"

[image]